# How to solve reccursive function with 2 variables

Tags: recursion

So I have a problem where I need to sum over a recursive function. The problem is that it is a 2 variables function and I can’t find any information on how to solve it. I know how to do it with 1 variable, but not with 2.

The problem:
$$f(k,i)=f(k-1,i)+f(k-1,i-1)$$

I found a similar post with
$f(k,i)=f(k-1,i)+f(k,i-1)$ but couldn’t understand how to convert the answer to my problem.

Base cases:
$$f(k,0)=1\text{ for every }k,$$
$$f(0,i)=1\text{ for every }i.$$

Comment: Would you recognize the recurrence if the boundary condition was instead $f(0,0)=1$ and $f(k,0)=0$ for $k\ne 0$?

Comment: Yes, i can change it to f(k,0)=0

Answer (score 1):

Here's a table of the values of $\ f(k,i)\ $ for $\ 0\le k\le9\ $ and $\ 0\le i\le5\ $.  By inspection, you can guess that $\ f(k,i)=2^k\ $ for $\ 0\le k\le i\ $, and this is easy enough to prove by induction.
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc }
i\\
\hline
5&1&2&4&8&16&32&63&120&219&382\\
4&1&2&4&8&16&31&57&99&163&256\\
3&1&2&4&8&15&26&42&64&93&130\\
2&1&2&4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46\\
1&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
\hline
k&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9
\end{array}$$
Note that the numbers along any diagonal to the right of the main diagonal, $\ k=i\ $,
are the sums of the numbers up the diagonal immediately to its left:
$$
f(k,k-a)=\sum_{r=a+1}^kf(r,r-a-1)
$$
for $\ k>a>0\ $.  Using this observation, I'm guessing that a general formula for the numbers to the right of the main diagonal is
$$
f(k,i)=2^k-\sum_{j=0}^{k-i-1}{k\choose j}
$$
for $\ k>i\ge0\ $. I've checked that the formula is correct for all the numbers in the above table, so I'm pretty sure  that it will hold in general.   I haven't bothered trying to prove it, but I expect that it should be fairly straightforward to do by induction.  I doubt that there's any simpler expression for the sums, $\ \sum_\limits{j=0}^{k-i-1}{k\choose j}\ $, of binomial coefficients.